# How to run sagemaker processing and training job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a processing and training job in sagemaker from console that is of left side of the panel of sagemaker, that processing job has no option to run it from console. Can someone tell how I can run that training job? Do I need a sagemaker notebook to run it? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVNqdT5ilOg&t=1173s

Answer (score 2):

This [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-mkt-algo-train.html#sagemaker-mkt-algo-train-console) from AWS documentation may help. It  describes how to run a training job from the console.  Essentially once you complete all the steps you can choose "Create training job" to run it (I believe the UI has changed a bit since the screenshot you posted above.)

You could also checkout this [video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQc8Itd4UTs&list=PLhr1KZpdzukcOr_6j_zmSrvYnLUtgqsZz&index=1) from AWS that gives overall information on how to run training jobs in SageMake dependeing on what you would like to achieve.